# first method in list

Tags: c#, list

I have this class:

```
public class Game
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Players{ get; set; }
    public int ReleaseYear{ get; set; }
}
```

I want to create a list,

```
List<Game> list = new List<Game>();
```

and look for one element, for example:

```
Game g = new Game();
g = (list.First(k => k.Players == 2)) as Game; // this line do nothing
```

But the program finishes doing nothing without throwing any exception, what is the problem?

Comment: What do you mean "it does nothing", is the value of g after the line has executed?  Why are you casting the result to Game if list is a 'List<Game>' then the result of `First()` will be an instance of `Game`

Comment: Seems to work fine. Are you checking the 'g' object? There should be selected element in it. Also its better to use list.First<Game>(k => k.Players == 2) to avoid casting.

Comment: @cornerback84: You don't need to explicitly state the type parameter to `First`; the compiler will infer it from the type of `list`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it helps, this works

```
        List<Game> list = new List<Game>();
        list.Add(new Game() { Players = 2, Name = "Football" });
        list.Add(new Game() { Players = 1 });
        list.Add(new Game() { Players = 2, Name = "Soccer" });

        Game g = list.First<Game>(k => k.Players == 2);
        //g will contain the "Football" game
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you populate the list? Try this:

```
var games = new List<Game> {
                new Game { Name = "Foo Bros.", Players = 2, ReleaseYear = 1983 },
                new Game { Name = "Hope", Players = 4, ReleaseYear = 1993 }
            };
var firstFourPlayerGame = games.First(g => g.Players == 4);
Console.WriteLine(firstFourPlayerGame.Name);
```

Output:

Hope

Answer (score 0):

It trows because the list is empty, and it will trow as well if you don't use FirstOrDefault and there is no item having Players == 2.

Comment: @blur and it is probably safer since in production will not crash if the list does not contain any element that satisfy your criteria